# Apps with Stack Overflow logo on Chrome Web Store and Android Market

Tags: support, logo, trademark

I'm developing a Google Chrome extension based on Stack Exchange APIs and it's almost finished.
I'm just thinking about my logo and I found a lot of apps on [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/stack%20overflow) and [Android Market](https://market.android.com/search?q=stack%20overflow&c=apps) with Stack Overflow logo which is in my opinion violating [the Stack Exchange Trademarks](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance). Am I right?

Comment: I see two on the Android Market: [1](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.Arabtechreview.Stackoverflow) [2](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.topixoft.top_stack_overflow).  A couple others are recognizable but significantly modified enough, I would think: [1](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.maxscheglov.stackoverflow) [2](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.blork.sowidget).  [StackAnywhere](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rectangularsoftware.stackanywhere) appears to contain the icons within the app, not sure if that's a problem?

Comment: I *love* the Stack Widget logo. It's a cool, non-problematic solution, yet still recognizable as connected with SO